# Array of objects, replace an object with a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects that represents the data of my model at any given time (a group of form controls on the stage of my app). The visual for this array of objects is attached here:

[image]

In this example, there are two objects on the stage, 0 and 1 by index. There could be only a single object or multiples.

When one of the objects in the array is selected it becomes the activeItem (see console.log above "this.activeItem"). In this case, the "Checkbox" item is the actively selected item.

In another part of my app, there is an editor that allows the user to modify the properties of this selected element. This properties editor has an Apply button that captures the form values and submits the updated properties back to the console.

My task is to take these updated/new properties and insert/replace the properties object of the activeItem with them and then update/rewrite the this.arrayOfObjects model to reflect the updated properties for the selected element.

As you can see from the screenshot, I have console.logged a reference to the properties object for the activeItem. I need to replace that object with my new updated properties object. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already record the `index` of all the objects in the array (including the active one), you can just get the edits of the user and store them in an obj and create a new obj merging the `edits` with `activeObj`:

```
const edittedObj = Object.assign(activeObj, edits) // creates new obj with applied edits
this.arrayOfObjects.splice(activeObj.dnd.index, 1, edittedObj) // puts editted obj into array
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an array of objects, you can set your active item to one of the objects, and that variable will be a reference to the object in the array. For example:

```
var array = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {x: 1}, {x: 2}];
console.log(array[0]); // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
var activeItem = array[0];
activeItem.a = 99;
console.log(array[0]); // {a: 99, b: 2, c: 3}
```

That way, writing the properties of activeItem writes the properties to the correct item in your array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

arrayOfObjects[1] and activeItem both hold a reference to the same object. Change your properties obj using one of these references and it will show up for the other, they're the same object.

```
this.activeItem.json.schema.properties = {{your_new_properties_object_here}}
```